# Ubuntu 20.04 loses tweaked settings after plugging in docking station

Tags: gnome, keyboard, gnome-tweaks

I have some keyboard settings changed through the Gnome Tweak Tool, such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>, and change layout on <kbd>R Alt</kbd>.

But I'm experiencing problems with that settings when plugging in my laptop to my docking station. These settings just stop working, although all checkboxes in Tweak Tool on their places. So, to reapply the settings I need to change something in keyboard settings of Tweak Tool. And it doesn't matter what to change, all the settings applying again simultaneously.

I reproduced it in Ubuntu 20.04 and Pop_Os! 20.04. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: I have the same problem. I thought I was going crazy. But it turns out it's a [bug with Gnome 3.38](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1899206). Looks to have been [recently fixed](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/merge_requests/1553) and will hopefully be released soon.

Answer (score 2):

Try downgrading gnome shell version (worked for me)

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell=3.36.1-5ubuntu1 gnome-shell-common=3.36.1-5ubuntu1
```

To avoid future upgrades to gnome shell

```
echo "gnome-shell hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

Similar issue is reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1899206)

Comment: It helps me. Thanks!